# Rust LDAP with auth

Tags: rust, ldap, ldap3

How do I connect to ldap using Rust?

All I could find from the online docs was this:

```
use ldap3::result::Result;
use ldap3::{LdapConn, Scope, SearchEntry};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut ldap = LdapConn::new("ldap://localhost:2389")?;
    let (rs, _res) = ldap
        .search(
            "ou=Places,dc=example,dc=org",
            Scope::Subtree,
            "(&(objectClass=locality)(l=ma*))",
            vec!["l"],
        )?
        .success()?;
    for entry in rs {
        println!("{:?}", SearchEntry::construct(entry));
    }
    Ok(ldap.unbind()?)
}
```

I'm looking for something like python's ldap3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After defining the LdapConn, you need to bind. You have to use distinguished name or email in the bind.

```
    let result = ldap
        .simple_bind("username@example.com", "password")
        .unwrap()
        .success();
    if result.is_err() {
        println!("This failed")
    } else {
        println!("IT WORKED!")
    }
```

A more practical application:

```rust
   assert!(ldap
        .simple_bind("username@example.com", "password")
        .unwrap()
        .success()
        .is_ok());
```

If you need more options like python's ldap3 you can use [LdapConnSettings](https://docs.rs/ldap3/0.6.1/ldap3/struct.LdapConnSettings.html) to specify some of the settings like tls

```rust
    let mut ldap: LdapConn = LdapConn::with_settings(
        LdapConnSettings::new()
            .set_no_tls_verify(true)
            .set_starttls(true),
        "ldap://localhost:2389"
    )
    .unwrap();
```

Comment: Note that the "email" is the AD account's userPrincipalName – it's only shaped like an email, but not necessarily an actual email address. (It's also an AD-specific feature; other LDAP systems generally do not support this shortcut and require a full DN.)